# combine three images using css and html

Tags: html, css, image

I have three images. I want to combine them

I am referring to this link

[https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp#:~:text=An%20element%20with%20position%3A%20absolute,moves%20along%20with%20page%20scrolling](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp#:%7E:text=An%20element%20with%20position%3A%20absolute,moves%20along%20with%20page%20scrolling).

I am trying to achieve this three combine images

I tried static and relative position but they did not work

```
 .object-left, .main-image  {
        position: absolute;
    }

 .object-right , .main-image{
         position: absolute;             //here I am using comma but not work 
}
```

.cshtml

```css
.object-left,
.main-image .object-right {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-4 image">
    <img class="object-left" src="~/Graphics/Services Page/obj1.svg" style="width:50px;height:50px;" /> //1 image
    <img class="main-image" src="~/Graphics/Services Page/Mobile app developement.svg" /> //2 image
    <img class="object-right" src="~/Graphics/Services Page/obj2.svg" style="width:50px;height:50px;" /> //3 image
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:100px;">
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <p class="description">asd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you use absolute positioning, the objects start at the upper-left corner of the parent (i.e. location 0x0), so all your three images appear on top of each other. All you need to do is tell them where they should be by adding the `left` property. The first image can stay at `left=0`, so you don't need to do anything. The second image must start at the width of the first image, `left=50px` in my example below. The third image must start at the total width of the fist and second image, `left=100px` in my example below.

Also remember that since you used absolute positioning on all three images and the parent doesn't have any other content, it will collapse. So you need to give it the height of the tallest image.

```css
.object-left {
  position: absolute;
}

.main-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}

.object-right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}

.image {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-4 image">
    <img class="object-left" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <img class="main-image" src="http://placehold.it/50x100" />
    <img class="object-right" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <p class="description">asd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: in the example above, all images are placed at the top of the parent by default. If you want some images to start at a different location, then give it a `top` property. In the example below, I gave the third image a `top=50px` property to align it with the bottom of the second image:

```css
.object-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.main-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
}

.object-right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
}

.image {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-4 image">
    <img class="object-left" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <img class="main-image" src="http://placehold.it/50x100" />
    <img class="object-right" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <p class="description">asd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do. I would remove the inline style on the object- images and put that in the css. I left the top, left, right on `.object-` empty so that you can put where you want to place them.

Does this make sense?

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
}

.object-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: ;
  left: ;
}

.main-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.object-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: ;
  right: ;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="object-left"></div>
  <div class="main-image"></div>
  <div class="object-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @niskuremdir well you have to set `top: ;` `right: ;` to have values for the right image, the same with the left image. top, right, bottom and left are values that you can set to tell the position where it should be placed. For me it is hard to know as you don't have the images.

Comment: You edited your question with 1, 2 and 3 with arrows, is that the position you want them in?

Comment: @ Dejan.S yes I forgot that thing